# Multiple 'databases' within one graph database

Tags: database-design, neo4j, graph-databases, database-partitioning

I use GrapheneDB for hosting my neo4j database (db).

**The problem**

I have `N` clients and am looking for ways to automatically separate their content (their unique db) such that:

- it does not overlap the data
- the speed of operations is not harmed.

**Option 1**

Since I am unfamiliar with creating new neo4j servers automatically, and want to keep the things simple, my idea is to attach an unique `databaseId` to every `node` and `relationship` in the graph.

Then obviously I would apply queries with that restriction in mind.

**Option 2**

Another idea would be to create a root node and create a relationship for all nodes with the rootnode.

**Questions**

My questions are:

- which option is better in terms of speed and by how much?
- is this a feasible method, i.e. do you see advantages/disadvantages?
- will it affect the speed when I have lots of data (`N --> /inf`)? My thought is that it will not since you apply the `databaseId` restriction (e.g. in `noSQL` this works perfectly fine), but I am not sure it will hold as well for a neo4j graph db.

Comment: The feature you're speaking of, for reference, is multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general suggestion (since I know nothing about your use cases), I would try to use a *disjoint set of node labels* for each "logical DB" (LDB). That would make it easy to create and access nodes that belong to a specific LDB. And, if you only create relationships between nodes with labels that belong to the same LDB, then graph traversals will also stay within the same LDB.

Neo4j can quickly get nodes by label, and you can also create indexes so that you can find label/property combinations efficiently.

Comment: Oke so if I understood well, that is option 1? (With indexing)

Comment: Option 1 (in which, I assume, LDBs would all share the same labels) is more heavyweight, since for performance you would have to create an index for every node label (e.g., `:Label1(databaseId)`, `:Label2(databaseId)`, etc.) and write extra code to always qualify all your queries by the correct `databaseId` property. Indexes take time to update when you add a node, and they also take up storage/memory. Since neo4j always adds new labeled nodes to the appropriate internal label collection, you might as well just use those label collections to find the nodes that belong to a LDB.

Comment: Ah wait a second so the label is actualy the thing like Movie, User etc. E.g.: CREATE (m:Movie). And you suggest to add multiple labels for each Node e.g. CREATE(m:Movie:LabelDb)? If correct, that sounds quite tricky. For instance, how do I set the labelname dynamically etc.

Comment: I was thinking more like `:Movie1` for LDB 1, `:Movie2` for LDB 2, etc. Since Cypher code is usually passed as a string to some API, you can just append the correct suffix to every "base" label string when generating the Cypher string.

Comment: Clear. Just as a follow up. You would not partition the relationship labels as well right? Just the nodes? No effect on performance?

Comment: Also, does it matter (for performance) that my label names are very long. E.g. `Movie49eabcjcgemshfshnwtrsfjhqg4hflerjnjsntzhfsdeoa09vstack`

Comment: Using partitioned type names (relationships have a "type" -- not "labels") should not be needed. Longer label names would take a tiny bit longer to generate on the client, transmit, and parse on the server, but I do not expect that there would be much of an impact on actual execution time or in storage of the resulting nodes (since a stored node references labels by id, not by name).